# reformatting an asus laptop and reinstalling Windows

Tags: windows-8.1, asus-laptop

This should be a simple process,but coming from a Mac background I find doing anything involving formatting and or installation of system software incredibly arcane in the PC world.

My issue is I was getting the dreaded BSOD on boot. After tons of googling, system level and anti malware scans etc, I came to the conclusion it was probably some typeof System kernel level compatability issue with 3rd party drivers. The issue seemed to resolve itself on its own but I couldn't sure it wasn't a virus or malware of some sort.
So I opted to completely reformat my hard drive and reinstall Windows.

1st problem > I don't have a recovery disc.
More googling and discovered I needed to recover my Product Key, download official Windows 8 ISO, and create a proper recovery disc. I chose the USB option.

2nd problem>when trying to reinstall Windows from my recovery USB, I get an error message saying that the product key doesn't match....
More googling and the suggested solution is to create a custom PID.txt file containing your officialWindows 8 Product key.
Tried this but didn't work, same message.

I give up! So far an entire weekend wasted on what should a simple 2-3hour process!!

Can any windows-hardware gurus help?

Comment: How did you install your Windows in the first place? What was its version? Windows 8? Do you still have recovery partition in your hard drive?

Comment: Came preinstalled with windows 8 pro. Since then upgraded to 8.1 . I think f9?? on boot is supposed to access a recovery partition on Asus laptops? Tried that, no luck...

Comment: Is there something I can check in the BIOS setup to confirm whether or not I have a recovery partition?

Comment: You can use "diskpart" and then "select disk" and "list partition" commands in command prompt after booting via a Windows recovery disk. Alternatively you can use [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) to see if you have a recovery partition. If yes, make that partition "active" using GParted, then your computer should boot using that partition and you will be able to reinstall your Windows. Let me remind you that first of all please take a backup image of your hard disk using Redo Backup or another alternative image software.

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't the built in DiskManager offer all the functionality of GParted?

Answer (score 0):

> when trying to reinstall Windows from my recovery USB, I get an error
>   message saying that the product key doesn't match....

Windows is very sensitive about matching CoA's (aka 'keys') and disk versions.
If you try to install windows 8 pro with a windows 8 pro iso or pendrive than it should just work. However if you use an other disc image (and there are eight of them) with a valid CoA/key for a different version then it will not work.

Worsse, two of the windows 8 versions are called 'with bing' (which is something you can uninstall immediately after installing the OS) and are means as sort-of-free OS's for OEMs. These trigger on a manufacturer specific key stored in the UEFI firmware.

These iso seem very hard to get (I spent a few days before I gave up and just bought a new legal windows installation). As far as I can tell you either make them somehow before your system gets corrupted or infected, or you pay for a DVD when you buy the laptop, or you become an OEM. The last might be a tad hard to do for just one laptop. :)

Windows 8.1N                6NPQ8-PK64X-W4WMM-MF84V-RGB89
    Windows 8.1                 334NH-RXG76-64THK-C7CKG-D3VPT
    Windows 8.1 Single Language Y9NXP-XT8MV-PT9TG-97CT3-9D6TC
    Windows 8.1 Professional N  JRBBN-4Q997-H4RM2-H3B7W-Q68KC
    Windows 8.1 Professional    XHQ8N-C3MCJ-RQXB6-WCHYG-C9WKB
    Windows 8.1 Professional with Media Center GBFNG-2X3TC-8R27F-RMKYB-JK7QT


IIRC similar keys existed for windows 8.0. That would at least tell you which version of the OS your ISOs are. Alternatively you could ofc. just redownload the iso's and write down the version.

 -->

Lastly, try to install windows with one of the generic keys. It might just auto activate on it own.

(Much to my surprise. I bought a nice new shiny win 10 pro. Installed on a windows 8.1 laptop for which I had no recovery key and it activated. Scared to change that atm).